# Rails test post content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd

Rails 6

how to post header AND body in rails test?

considering tipps like [this](https://tamouse.github.io/blog/swaac/2013/09/17/json-how-to-send-raw-post-data-in-a-rails-functional-test-stack-overflow.html)

**Rails test/integration**

```
require 'test_helper'

class DataTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "Post Profiles" do
    post "/candy/user/profiles", {headers: {:authorization => @session[:authorization]}}, {'RAW_POST_DATA' => 'something'}
  end

end
```

**Result**

```
DataTest#test_Post_Profiles:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1)
    test/integration/candy/data_test.rb:31:in `block in <class:DataTest>'
```

**that too didnt help**
could not see any sent body in controller by `request.raw_post` or `request.body.read`

```
def raw_post(action, params, body)
    @request.env['RAW_POST_DATA'] = body
    response = post(action, params)
    @request.env.delete('RAW_POST_DATA')
    response
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw post is request body, in modern rails you can pass a string for `params` parameter:

```rb
  post "/candy/user/profiles", headers: {authorization: @session[:authorization]}, params: 'something'
```